# Is it possible to make 'a variable' render as 'a-variable' using Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, pug, templating

Is it possible to make `a variable` render as `a-variable` using Jade?

A use case for this would be:

```
- pageTitle = 'Page Title';

body(class="#{pageTitle}")
  h1 #{pageTitle}
```

This would render as:

```
<body class="page-title">
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
```

Comment: you want to transform camelCase to dash? `fooBar -> foo-bar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need a helper function and then just pass your variable name to it:

```
- pageTitle = 'Page Title';

- var transform = function(camelCase) {
-  return camelCase.replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
- }
body(class=transform("pageTitle"))
  h1 #{pageTitle}
```